# If Shabbat falls immediately after Pesach, what could Sephardim use for Hamotzi on Shabbat?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, matzah, challah-shabbat-bread, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

If Matzah is mezonot for some Sepharadim, and Shabbat were to fall immediately after Pesach, what could such Sephardim use for hamotzi on Shabbat, given the obligation of lechem mishneh? One could not use Matzah, because it is not considered hamotzi in this scenario. One could not use leavened bread because one could not own or buy it during pesach and one could not buy it once Shabbat has started.

Comment: Why is matzah "mezonot for some Sephardim"?

Answer (score 3):

If you are kove'ah seuda on a mezonot food, treating it as a meal rather than a snack, then it is treated as hamotzi. That should solve the problem. Source: http://www.kosherveyosher.com/hamotzi-vs-mezonos.html

Comment: That's true for some mezonot food, but certainly not all. No matter how much spaghetti you eat, you'll never make hamotzi on it

Comment: Also, just because you can make a _hamotzi_ on it doesn't prove that it works for _lechem mishnah_ on _shabbos_

Comment: @daniel the OP didn't ask about lechem mishneh. (And while your point is logically true in principle, I don't see why it should they shouldn't​count)

Comment: True. I did not ask specifically about lechem mishneh, however, that was my intention. Any way to have lechem mishneh in this scenario?

Comment: @user2543822 I've edited your question according to your clarification, but in the future you should do so yourself.

Answer (score 0):

He can make a nice fluffy *challah* out of *matzah* meal.

Although it was a Pas Habaah Bekisnin while it was flat it would become Hamotzi when changed to proper bread shape. As we find regarding the [cooked food being re-baked](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.168.14).

חָלוּט (פֵּרוּשׁ כְּמִין פַּת חוֹלְטִין אוֹתוֹ בְּרוֹתְחִין) שֶׁאַחַר כָּךְ אֲפָאוֹ בַּתַּנּוּר, פַּת גָּמוּר הוּא וּמְבָרֵךְ עָלָיו הַמּוֹצִיא.

Comment: If this is possible, why don't people do it every day of Pesach?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't have an issue making Hamotzi on Matzah. I have no motivation to do so.

Comment: Maybe that's fine for you, but clearly others would prefer bread sometimes. Clearly this isn't possible.

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you basing that merely in the fact that nobody does this? The Halachah is that if it is rebaked and has the form of bread it is _hamotzi_. Where's the hole?

Comment: The hole is this won't work. The gluten in matza meal is already denatured from the heat of the initial baking. it wont make a nice bread afterwards. You should know it doesn't work from the fact that no one does it.

Comment: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/80808/8291

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh, the technical aspect? Well, you can use beaten eggs, baking soda, seltzer... We have a very innovative culinary market these days. But this part of the argument is definitely not my stronger point.

Comment: If you add eggs or too much other stuff it's probably not Hamotzi for Sefardim.

Comment: What makes you say that quote also applies when the pieces are less than a kezayit and remixed together?

Answer (score -1):

A Sepharadi person could set aside his fresh soft matzot he made on Friday. If he stores them well they should last past Erev Shabbat and he could use them for lunch on Shabbat. Since these are Sepharadi matzot they are hammotzi without needing any halakhic loopholes about "making it the center of the meal."